# ActionScript 3.0; looping audiofiles

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, flash, audio, actionscript

Currently trying to loop a sound clip (imported mp3 to library) endlessly in my Actionscript 3 project. This is my current set up:

```
var sound:Sound = new bgm();
function playSound():void
{
    var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play(80);
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    SoundChannel(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, onComplete);
    playSound();
}
 //end loop
```

This doesn't report any errors; however it doesn't play any sounds either. Am I missing something? Do I need to import something to the .fla before it can register the sound?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Is this solved? Please mark the answer as correct. Like @Null said you must run that `playSound` function by putting a `playSound();` somewhere in your code, try it as next line after `var sound:Sound = new bgm();`. Also no need for **80** just use `sound.play();` since it will repeat on sound playback complete...

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function `playSound()` initially.